# ввод данных в новое окно браузера

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

на многих сайтах (например, geogebra.org) есть подтверждение в новом открывающемся окне браузера. как автоматизировать ввод данных в это окно?

[image: пример]